# Cannot share attached hard drive

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

I have spent a lot of time over the last few days trying to get two identical Ubuntu machines to share their attached drives with Windows. But, no success. Now I turn to the experts.

I get it right to share a /home//data file and can read and write at will to such folder. But, I cannot get the attached drive /media//Data (the disk's name is Data) set up so that I can access it from the Windows machine (I can see it in Windows, but I get the message "You do not have permission to access \192.168.1.89\Data.").

As far as I am concerned the permissions are in place. In actual fact, to get that out of the way, most of my permissions on the Data disk, and the disk itself, and the /media/ are set to 777 (which I will change when I get it working).

What is then so different about an attached drive? The disks tool report it as being "HPFS/NTFS (Bootable)".

The computers each have a 64 Gb SSD boot drive and then an 1 Tb HDD for data (named Data). It is this disk that I want to share, so that I can backup Windows machines to folders on it.

Comment: I do not seem to be able to attract answers to this issue. Should I then install Windows on this machine to make it accessible? I am really frustrated and in need of help! It's now been five days ....